# Желтые границы в письме под Samsung Email

Tags: html, css, email, вёрстка-email, табличная-верстка

Здравствуйте!
Верстаю email-письмо, во всех клиентах отображается нормально, и только под Samsung Email появляются какие-то желтые границы. В коде этого цвета нет вообще.
Не пойму откуда они взялись и куда копать?

Код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0 auto !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      height: 100% !important;
      width: 100% !important;
    }
    
    a,
    a:visited {
      color: #13c1fe;
    }
    
    img.rounded-image {
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body class="body" bgcolor="#ffffff;" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;background-color: #ffffff;">

  <table width="100%" style="width:100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="center">
        <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="center">

              <table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <tr>
                  <td width="580" colspan="2" height="60"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left">
                    <!-- content -->
                  </td>
                  <td align="right">
                    <table>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="middle">

                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <tr>
                  <td height="60"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="580">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/580x220" style="width:580px;" width="580" border="0" editable />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="580" bgcolor="#fffceb">
                    <!-- content -->
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td width="580" style="height:67px;"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" width="580">
                    <span style="font-size: 22px;text-align: center;color: #000000;">
                                                Отзывы пользователей
                                            </span>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="height:30px;"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table width="580" class="review-item" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#f5ffea">
                <tr>
                  <td width="580">
                    <!--content-->
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <tr>
                  <td width="580" style="height:50px;"></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!--wrapper table end-->
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="center" bgcolor="#e7f8fe" style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;">
        <!--wrapper table-->
        <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="center">
              <!-- footer author -->
              <table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td width="580">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td style="width:110px;">
                          <!--image-->
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <div style="padding:15px;">
                            <!-- content -->
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <!--wrapper table end-->

      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td valign="top" align="center" bgcolor="#426774" style="padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:30px;">
        <!-- footer social & apps -->
        <table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="580">

              <table width="580" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td width="290" valign="top">
                    <!-- content -->
                  </td>
                  <td width="290" valign="top">

                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>


            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: Желтые границы слева и справа]

Comment: посмотрите в инспекторе, что отвечает за данный стиль кода.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в атрибуте `bgcolor="#ffffff"` тэга `body`. Его нужно было убрать.

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в главный css файл этот код и все должно исправиться

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: css файл для почтовой рассылки к сожалению не подойдет

Comment: @kizoso, ну тогда такая мысль данные атрибуты  width, height,  bgcolor давно устарели, вполне вероятно, что из-за них искажает...  надо это все  в правила в  css  прописывать...

Comment: для веба устарели, для почтовой рассылки это зачастую единственный верный способ указать стиль

Comment: @kizoso,  не буду скрывать, для меня это новость... буду знать...

Comment: вставил в тэг body нулевые margin & padding и width 100%, никакого эффекта...

Answer (score 0):

Оберните вашу главную таблицу в таблицу с единственной ячейкой вроде вот такой:

```html
<table width='100%' height='100%' >
    <tr>
        <td width='100%' height='100%' bgcolor='#e2e3e7'>
            <!-- Здесь ваша главная таблица -->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Тоже не сработало. Эта таблица дала серую границу вокруг основного содержания письма, но желтые границы образуются за над ними.